# Why say 「いるわけ」when わけ isn't an animate object?

Tags: grammar, idioms

From the first episode of *Death Note*:

> この世に不必要な人間を消すことのできるヤツがいるか？
>
> **いる**わけがない

Why is いる used here, when わけ ("reasoning") isn't an animate object? Shouldn't this be "ある訳" instead?

Comment: いる doesn't apply to わけ. Try parsing that again, paying close attention to the first sentence that "いるわけがない" is answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sentence is an answer to the one right before.

> （～ことのできるヤツが）いるわけがない。"There cannot be (a guy who can...)"

Therefore the subject of the verb いる in this context is 「不必要な人間を消すことのできるヤツ」, which is animate.